# (ionic cordova resources )Uploading source images to prepare for transformations error

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I run this code:

```
ionic cordova resources
```

but gives me an error;  how can I fix this error?

```
Collecting resource configuration and source images - done!
√ Filtering out image resources that do not need regeneration - done!
× Uploading source images to prepare for transformations - failed!
HTTP Error 503: POST https://res.ionic.io/api/v1/upload
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Application Error</title>
                <style media="screen">
                  html,body,iframe {
                        margin: 0;
                        padding: 0;
                  }
                  html,body {
                        height: 100%;
                        overflow: hidden;
                  }
                  iframe {
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                        border: 0;
                  }
                </style>
          </head>
          <body>
                <iframe src="//www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/application-error.html"></iframe>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Seems to be an issue with this specific ionic service, I am getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

look here: https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360045361254-Resource-generations-fails-with-error-HTTP-Error-503-POST-https-res-ionic-io-api-v1-upload-

npm uninstall -g ionic

npm install -g @ionic/cli

npm install -g cordova-res